# jQuery UI Accordion icons not showing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I'm new to jQuery UI, but I can't figure out why this isn't working.

I have a simple accordion, and I'm trying to get the icons to show up. Here is my CoffeeScript:

```
$ ->
  $( '#accordion' ).accordion
    collapsible: true
    heightStyle: "content"
    icons:
      header: "ui-icon-triangle-1-e"
      activeHeader: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
```

In my application.js file I'm already including the follwing:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.all
```

EDIT 1:

Relevant part of Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.12'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

Comment: can you show me your Gemfile?

Comment: Yep! I just added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have tried jquery ui accordion and everything is ok.

<kbd>**[simple-jquery-ui-accordion rails 3.2.13](https://github.com/fauzieuy/simple-jquery-ui-accordion)**</kbd>

```
$ ->
  $( '#accordion' ).accordion
    collapsible: true
    heightStyle: "content"
    icons:
      header: "ui-icon-arrowthick-1-e"
      activeHeader: "ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s"
```

I think the issue on your views or you forgot to include `*= require jquery.ui.all` on `application.css`

```
*= require_self
*= require jquery.ui.all
*= require_tree .
```

Make sure everything your script is correct

Comment: Strange. I guess it must be something in my styles that is hiding the ui elements from showing up. I'll keep digging. At least I know I'm not doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Is Header and activeHeader suppose to be a value for the icons key?

From the example: http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-icons

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "icons", { "header": "ui-icon-plus", "activeHeader": "ui-icon-minus" } );
```

it looks like it 's a different argument.

which should look more like this

```
$(".selector").accordion "option", "icons",
  header: "ui-icon-plus"
  activeHeader: "ui-icon-minus"
```

Comment: I wasn't really sure. I tried both, but doing the above suggestion just breaks the accordion.

Comment: I cant see anything wrong, It should be the views. Make shure everything is nested correctly.